# How do you change the cis-trans isomerism of compounds?

Tags: synthesis, stereochemistry

I would like to know a general procedure for the synthesising cis isomers from their trans counterparts and vice versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, any setup that gives enough energy to the compound can isomerize it. This can be done by heating it, irradiating it with visible or UV light, or by using a catalyst (reducing the energy required for transition rather than supplying more energy). Excitation of electrons from the $\pi$ to the $\pi^*$ (bonding orbital to anti-bonding orbital) allow free rotation about the $\sigma$ bond. Relaxation back to the $\pi$ orbital locks the configuration. The specific procedures depend on the compound of interest.

FYI, photoisomerization (light-induced isomerization) is the principle on which sight is based.

Comment: By the way does photoisomerisation only induce the transition between cis and trans isomers? i.e. can dextrorotatory and levorotatory swapping occur due to photoisomerisation?

Comment: @BrentonHorne Changing from cis to trans may change the molecule from + to -, but it will not change the R/S configuration of any stereocenter. The +/- property does not depend on the absolute configuration of the stereocenters in any useful way.

Answer (score 0):

As a particular example of what buckminst is talking about, one common undergraduate organic chemistry laboratory experiment is the one where a tube full of dimethyl maleate is isomerized to dimethyl fumarate, with the help of sunlight and a teeny amount of bromine. Since solid dimethyl fumarate has low solubility in liquid dimethyl maleate, this makes for a nice visual demonstration. See e.g. [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ed018p477) and [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/TF9656101138).